# Web.API and FromBody

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm a bit confused.  I have a controller (derived from ApiController) that has the following method:

```
[ActionName("getusername")]
public string GetUserName(string name)
{
    return "TestUser";
}
```

My routing is set up like this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ActionApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

I kept getting a 400 error when I try to hit `/api/mycontroller/getusername/test` with a GET in fiddler.

I found that everything worked when I added `[FromBody]` to the name parameter in GetUserName.

I was somehow thinking that `[FromBody]` was used for `HttpPost`, signalling that the parameter was in the body of the post, and would therefore not be needed for a `GET`.  Looks like I was wrong though.

How does this work?

Comment: Did you try to rename 'name' to 'id'?  Your routing is expecting a parameter named 'id' to map into.

Comment: Also, does adding `[FromBody]` actually set the 'name' parameter to the value 'test'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to either change your routing to:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ActionApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{name}",
    defaults: new { name = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

or change the name of your parameter to:

```
[ActionName("getusername")]
public string GetUserName(string id)
{
    return "TestUser";
}
```

Note: Additional routing parameters must match method parameter names.

Comment: This did it.  I didn't realize the parameter name had to match the routing... thought it was just a placeholder.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do the following if it is closer to what you were looking for:

```
// GET api/user?name=test
public string Get(string name)
{
    return "TestUser";
}
```

This assumes you are using an `ApiController` named `UserController` and allows you to pass your `name` parameter as a query string. This way, you don't have to specify the `ActionMethod` but rather rely on the HTTP verb and matching route.

Comment: I think this is the way to go- no route changes, parameters can be named whatever you want....

Comment: @Nicros I was just considering the same problem and have come to the same conclusion independently. When that sort of thing happens there's a fair chance we're both right.